# Accessing non-existent property of module.exports inside circular dependency NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, module.exports

Im having some issues when using module.exports inside NodeJS, and I've followed multiple guides, and im almost certain Im doing it right.
I have to scripts, main.js and event.js. Im trying to share a function from main.js to event.js, but its not working. Here is the code:

Main.js

```
function Scan(){
    if(fs.readdirSync('./events/').length === 0){
        console.log(colors.yellow('Events Folder Empty, Skipping Scan'))
    } else {
        var events = fs.readdirSync('./events/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.json'))
                for(const file of events){
                    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./events/' + file);
                    let cJSON = JSON.parse(rawdata);
                }
                events.sort()
                tevent = events[0]
                StartAlerter()
                }
}

module.exports = { Scan };
```

Event.js

```
const main = require('../main')

main.Scan;
```

This returns the error:

```
(node:19292) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Scan' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please show you file system. is the import statement accurate ?

Comment: Main.js is in the parent directory of event.js. I have no idea if the import statement is accurate or not, as im not all that experienced with js

Comment: if both main.js and event.js are in the same directory, then the import statement should be 

const main = require('./main')

Does this solve it ?

Comment: They arent in the same directory, main is in the parent directory of event

Comment: Where does the main module import the event module? And *why* do these import each other?

Comment: @gjoe did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am having similar problems & can't seem to find any solutions thus far.

Comment: @ChrisP yes, I did module.exports = { Scan };
Before the function was defined, then referenced the file by going
const main = require('../main')
Then I ran
main.Scan() to execute the Scan function from event.js without any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, heres what I did differently:

```
module.exports = { Scan };
```

Is declared **before** the Scan function is defined, like so:

```
module.exports = { Scan };
function Scan(){
//Code
}
```

Then in event.js, I wrote

```
const main = require('../main')
```

As it is now a module, and can be used with the require() function.
Then to execute the funciton in event.js, I write

```
main.Scan()
```

To execute it.

Comment: Moving the `module.exports = { Scan };` does not change anything, the `function Scan` is hoisted anyway.

Comment: Hey @gjoe,  I tried this. But it did not work. I don't think the positioning mattered at all. However, the problem is from Javascript destructing. I was able to fix mine by changing the way I accessed the function from another file.

Answer (score 7):

I  discovered that the arrangement had no effect in the error.

I simply changed the way I exported the function from the Main.js

from:

```
module.exports = { Scan };
```

to:

```
exports.Scan = Scan
```

And in  Event.js, I was able to access the file like this

```
const main = require("./Main.js");
let result = main.Scan();
```

This solved my problem, I hope it helps another developer

Answer (score 2):

I am gonna answer it using a simple example, like in this case below:

1. File A has 3 functions to process database activity:  function
   `addDB`, `updateDB`, and `delData`;
2. File B has 2 functions to process User activity on smartphone:
   function `addHistory`, and `editHistory`;

Function `updateDB` in file A is calling function `editHis` in file B, and function `editHistory` is calling function `updateDB` in file A. This is what we called circular-dependency. And we need to prevent it by only giving output of state from `editHistory` and the rest will be processed inside file A.

```js
//ORIGINAL FUNCTIONS which caused CIRCULAR DEPENDENCY
function updateDB() {
  //process update function here
  //call function in fileB
  const history = require("fileB.js");
  await history.editHistory(data).then((output) => {
    if(output["message"] === "success"){
      response = {
        state: 1,
        message: "success",
      };
    }
  });
  return response; 
}

//THIS is the WRONG ONE
function editHistory() {
  //process function to edit History here
  //call function in fileA
  const file = require("fileA.js");
  await file.updateDB(data).then((output) => { //You should not call it here
    if(output["message"] === "success") {
      output = {
        state: 1,
        message: "success",
      };
    }
  });
  return output; 
}

//==================================================//
//THE FIX
function updateDB() {
  //process function here
  const history = require("fileB.js");
  await history.editHistory(data).then((output) => {
    if(output["message"] === "success"){
      await updateDB(data).then((output) => {
        response = {
          state: 1,
          message: "success",
        };
      });
    } else {
      log("Error");
    }
  });
  return response; 
}

function editHistory() {
  //process function to edit History here
  // No more calling to function inside the file A
  output = {
    state: 1,
    message: "success",
  };
  return output; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

better try :

```js
module.exports = Scan;
```

Comment: There's no destructuring anywhere

Comment: it is true, I have confused concepts, thanks for the observation.