# Error message when running "react-native start"

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-native-cli

**when running the "react-native start" command I got this error:**

(node:14668) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error No Metro config found in C:\Users\User\Desktop\firstProject.

**Here are the steps of what I did: **
1- I installed the latest version of node and npm.
2- installed react native cli using "npm install -g react-native-cli"
3- I created the react-native project using "react-native init MyProject"
4- Then I ran "react-native start" and got the error message

Comment: There are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713565/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67477093/) and various answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77579239). Do any of them help?